# Creating a Grayscale image in Visual C++ from a float array

Tags: c++, image

I have an array of grayscale pixel values (floats as a fraction of 1) that I need to display, and then possibly save. The values just came from computations, so I have no libraries currently installed or anything. I've been trying to figure out the CImage libraries, but can't make much sense of what I need to do to visualize this data. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: There are quite a few ways to display the data or create images (surprisingly, one of the simplest I've used was DirectX's D3DX create/fill/save texture functions), but all you need is to multiply each point by 255 and smear across all color channels (so 1.0 maps to [255,255,255]). I'll add a larger answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best solution for this problem was to use the SFML library (www.sfml-dev.org). Very simple to use, but must be compiled from source if you want to use it with VS2010.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach which I've used with some success is to take D3DX's texture functions to create a Direct3D texture and fill it. There is some overhead in starting up D3D, but it provides you with multi-thread-able texture creation and built-in-ish viewing, as well as saving to files without much more fuss.

If you're not interested in using D3D(X), some of the specifics here won't be useful, but the generator should help figure out how to output data for any other library.

For example, assuming an existing D3D9 device `pDevice` and a noise generator (or other texture data source) `pGen`:

```
IDirect3DTexture9 * pTexture = nullptr;
D3DXCreateTexture(pDevice, 255, 255, 0, 0, D3DFMT_R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &pTexture);
D3DXFillTexture(pTexture, &texFill, pGen);
D3DXSaveTexture("texture.png", D3DXIFF_PNG, pTexture, NULL);
```

The generator function:

```
VOID WINAPI texFill(
    D3DXVECTOR4* pOut, 
    CONST D3DXVECTOR2* pTexCoord, 
    CONST D3DXVECTOR2* pTexelSize, 
    LPVOID pData,  
) {
    // For a prefilled array:
    float * pArray = (float *)pData;
    float initial = pArray[(pTexCoord->y*255)+pTexCoord->x];

    // For a generator object:
    Generator * pGen = (Generator*)pData; // passed in as the third param to fill
    float initial = pGen->GetPixel(pTexCoord->x, pTexCoord->y);

    pOut->x = pOut->y = pOut->z = (initial * 255);
    pOut->w = 255; // set alpha to opaque
}
```

- D3DXCreateTexture: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- D3DXFillTexture: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172833(v=vs.85).aspx
- D3DXSaveTextureToFile: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205433(v=vs.85).aspx

Corresponding functions are available for volume/3D textures. As they are already set up for D3D, you can simply render the texture to a flat quad to view, or use as a source in whatever graphical application you may want.

So long as your generator is thread-safe, you can run the create/fill/save in one thread per texture, and generate multiple slices or frames simultaneously.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll give it a shot. I've never used D3DX before though, what is a "D3DX Device (pDevice)" and how do I get it?

Comment: A D3D9 device is a rendering context. You have to create one by calling [Direct3DCreate9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219685(v=vs.85).aspx), then [CreateDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174313(v=vs.85).aspx) on the returned object. It's very possible using D3D(X) is overkill, depending on your application, but it will likely work.

Comment: And which header would I find this in? I can't seem to find the right one. Also, I tried doing it just with CImage(), but am getting an "assertion failed" error on image.SetPixel(x, y, color). Any thoughts why?

Comment: No idea why you're getting errors with CImage, I'm not familiar with their library much at all. Depending on your compiler, you may have `d3d9.h` available, or you may need the DirectX SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PNM image format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#File_format_description) without any libraries whatsoever. (The format itself is trivial). However it's pretty archaic and you'll have to have an image viewer that supports it. IvanView, for example, supports it on Windows.